# SyntaxError: invalid syntax, I don't know how to fix this code. What's wrong with it? And how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

The part of the code that produced the error

```
def modinverse(a,26):
  
  for x in range(0,26):
    if(((a%26)*(b%26))%26 == 1):
      return x
  return -1

print(modinverse(a,26))
```

Here is the error I got

```
  File "main.py", line 51
    def modinverse(a,26):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked,it looks good. The spellings are fine, brackets and stuff are closed,  I don't know what to do. I can't see what's gone wrong.
I ran this on replit.

Comment: What do you mean to have `26` as a *parameter*?

Comment: that is the number of alphabets

Comment: i'm trying to make an affine cipher decoder

Comment: actually, i should change them all to 25 because my 'A' starts with a value of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `def modinverse(a,26)` should be something like `def modinverse(a,b)` or `def modinverse(a,b=26):`?

In the first case you are declaring a parameter with the name `26`.

Comment: '''def modinverse(a,b=26):''' works